# Get latest value based on another column and independently sum another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Situation:**

I have a table with paid and free transactions with a balance column that combines both the free and paid transactions.

**Objective:**

I need to get the total paid transactions and the most recent balance

**Structure:**

```
+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+------------+
| member_id | balance | amount |    type     | issue_date |
+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+------------+
| varchar   | int     | int    | pay or free | datetime   |
+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+------------+
```

**Current query:**

```
        select t1.member_id, t2.balance, sum(t1.amount) as total
        from table AS t1
        inner join (select member_id, 
                            balance, 
                            ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by member_id order by issue_date desc) AS ranks 
                    from table
                    ) AS t2 on t1.member_id=t2.member_id and t2.ranks = 1
        where [type] = 'pay'
        group by t1.member_id, t2.balance
```

It seems to work but looks extremely inefficient for tables with millions of rows where the issue_date isn't indexed.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses window functions and `select distinct`:

```
select distinct t.member_id,
       first_value(case when t.type = 'pay' then t.balance end) over (partition by t.member_id order by (case when t.type = 'pay' then 1 else 2 end), t.issue_date desc), 
       sum(t.amount) over (partition by t.member_id) as total
from table t;
```

Unfortunately, SQL doesn't have a `first_value()` aggregation function.

Comment: why did you remove the where statements and instead included in the case statements of the first_value clause?
wouldn't it be more efficient to have the where statement 'pay' and have the logic as such: first_value(t.balance) over (partition by t.member_id order by t.issue_date desc) as balance

Comment: and my ssms has first_value

Comment: @RogerSteinberg . . . because you want the total amount.